# Interpret (and use) the output from Fabric local command

Tags: python, fabric

I would like to use a Fabric command to set up a local development environment, and as part of that I want to be able to set up a git remote. This works fine:

```
from fabric.api import local

def set_remote():
    """ Set up git remote for pushing to dev."""
    local('git remote add myremote git@myremote.com:myrepo.git')
```

The problem comes with running this a second time - when the local command bombs because the remote already exists. I'd like to prevent this by checking if the remote exists first:

In pseudocode, I'd like to do the following:

```
if 'myremote' in local('git remote'):
    print 'Remote \'myremote\' already exists.'
else:
    local('git remote add myremote git@myremote.com:myrepo.git')
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`settings`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings) context manager to `warn_only`:

```
from fabric.context_managers import settings

with settings(warn_only=True):
    # some command we are all right with having fail
```

Alternately, you can set the `capture` keyword arg on the [`local`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.local) command to `True`:

```
if 'myremote' in local('git remote', capture=True):
    print 'Remote \'myremote\' already exists.'
else:
    local('git remote add myremote git@myremote.com:myrepo.git')
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you so much for that - I'll use `capture=True`, although I think letting it fail is probably more pythonic (easier to ask forgiveness...etc.)

Comment: BTW _ I don't suppose you'd like to answer this one as well would you  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713156/how-to-set-environment-variables-using-fabric