# Django, Fabric: What is the best way to manage secret keys to deploy Django projects?

Tags: python, django, deployment, fabric

For now I'm trying to store SECRET_KEY in environment variable:

```
# settings/base.py

def get_env_variable(var_name):
    """ Get the environment variable or return exception """
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = 'Set the {} environment variable'.format(var_name)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable('SECRET_KEY')
```

And I cant realize how should I deploy my project with Fabric:

```
@task
def deploy():
    syncdb()
    collectstatic()

@task
def collectstatic():
    dj('collectstatic')
    with cd('{django_root}/static'.format(**env)):
        fix_permissions()

@task
def syncdb():
    dj('syncdb')

@task
def dj(command):
    run('{virtualenv_dir}/bin/python {django_root}/manage.py {dj_command}'.format(dj_command=command, **env))
```

Which method to setting env vars will be the best in this situation?
I'm really want to make this automatically and use this fabscript many times. At the same time I dont want to store secret information in fabfile or in the settings because I will push them to public repo.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question - are you asking how to [set environment variables with fabric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713156/how-to-set-environment-variables-using-fabric), or how to generate a secret key?

Comment: Im asking how to use fabric for setting environment variables on the deployment server permanently.

Answer (score 1):

It would be pointless to set the secret key automatically as part of deployment because the secret key can be know by looking at your deployment files. (You source files may be in a less secure location, e.g. source control, and the point of separating out the secret key in the first place is so someone with access to the source cannot see what it is).

You have set the secret manually once on the deployment system first.

(In your case set the environment variable which can be done by adding a line to `/etc/enviroment` e.g. `MY_DJANGO_APP_SECRET_KEY=mysecretkeyvalue`)